# Auto-revert for changed pdf buffers?

Tags: org-export, pdf-tools, revert-buffer, auto-revert-mode

Specifically in the content of exporting org->latex->pdf when using pdftools to view the resulting pdf, how can I stop emacs from asking me if I want to revert the pdf buffer and instead just auto-revert without asking?

I tried:

```
(add-hook 'pdf-view-mode-hook (lambda () (auto-revert-mode 1)))
```

and also:

```
(add-hook 'pdf-tools-enabled-hook (lambda () (auto-revert-mode 1)))
```

But neither of these had an effect.

Comment: See `revert-without-query`, I suppose.

Comment: `(add-hook 'pdf-view-mode-hook (lambda () (auto-revert-mode 1)))` worked fine for me. After doing that, open a PDF file and check that the mode line shows `(PDFView ARev)`: if that's the case, the PDF buffer should automatically revert from the PDF file every time you update that file (e.g. with `C-c C-e l p`).

Answer (score 0):

I use `M-x auto-revert-mode` in the actual buffer with pdf.

Comment: Shouldn't the `(add-hook 'pdf-view-mode-hook (lambda () (auto-revert-mode 1)))` automatically do that in any case?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25630)